# Blank screen after login attempt in PHP

Tags: php

I have created a login form using PHP, though once I enter the username and password it redirects to my authentication page which becomes blank. I have tried entering details which are correct and incorrect but receive no response from either, any help would be appreciated, my code is as follows:

**Login.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <style>



form {
    text-align:center;
}

  </style>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>HIS - Login</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>

  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>Hospital Information System</h1>

</div>

<div class="container" align="center">

<div class="card" style="width:400px" >

  <img src="images/avatar.png" alt="Card image" class="img-thumbnail">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title" align="center">Login</h4>
    <p class="card-text">

    <form action="authenticate.php" method="POST">
   Username<br />
   <input type="text" name="username" />
   <br />
   Password<br />
   <input type="password" name="password" />
   <br />
   <br />
   <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"></a>
  </form>
    </div>

</div>

</div>
</html>
```

**Authenticate.php**

```
<?php
// Initialize the session

session_start();

// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: index.php");
    exit;
}

// Include config file
include "connection.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter username.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }

    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT username, password FROM PATIENT WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();

                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            

                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: index.php");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

**Connection.php**

```
<?php


  // server details hidden

  // Create connection
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  // Check connection
  if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
?>
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors, make sure you use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` when debugging.

Comment: Check your web server's error log, if your script is fataling, it should contain a dump of the error.

Comment: You have lots of "error messages" getting assigned to variables but never printed to the screen. The comments suggest that they are getting displayed but they are not

Comment: Don't think you ever store anything in $hashed_password. Most likely not the problem, but I think that's a separate issue.

Comment: what does your `index.php` look like? you seem to just be redirecting the user there after validating credentials, but you don't seem to be doing anything with the variables with the error messages, etc